E15 jaguar X Jl portfolio, 2015
Already replaced thermostat Continues to overheat,
2 questions;

What are the symptoms of a malfunctioning coolant temperature sensor?
I bought some blue devil radiator flush and the head gasket sealant repair it says to use it exactly as directed so my question is what if it overheats while you're running it through the process as directed....should I turn it off or just  Let it do it's thing? Thanks.

